# Bandwidth (Data rate) of a laser beam when no datasheet exists for the module

Tags: datasheet, laser, baudrate, laser-diode, bit-rate

I ordered a large number of laser modules that look like the following:

[image: laser modules]

When inspecting mine with a basic multimeter, I noticed a 90 ohm smd resistor is fitted on the module. I see no other components fitted on.

I tried searching for datasheets for different laser modules to get an idea on the maximum data rate these modules can produce, and so far I found one source online indicating its module (that looks like a large box with two beams) is 400hz maximum bandwidth (data rate).

I also found listings in the search engine indicating that some laser beams can go much faster than 400hz.

What is the actual specific name and unit number for these modules? I want to look the name up so I can get the datasheet and figure out the absolute maximum data rate I can use. (I'm doing slow data transmission through lasers as a test).

Comment: Umm... maybe ask whoever you ordered them from?  It's highly unlikely that anyone can randomly give you a full part number from a picture...  Of course, with a waveform generator and scope you can quickly figure this out on your own.

Comment: If you want a laser that goes "much faster" you don't connect to it with a 10 cm wire. These are likely not intended to be modulated at all. But you might get 400 Hz or 100 kHz out of them---just try it.

Comment: An LED might work as a detector.

Comment: *"I ordered a large number of laser modules"* - what was the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The baud rate you can squeeze out of a laser is wildly variant between lasers. Try contacting the company. You can also test it yourself if the company isn't helpful.